# Extract FDF Annotation

Tags: c#, itext

I have FDF file saved in my machine, I want to extract Annotation from fdf. I'm using Itextsharp in c#.

I have found the PDF reader method. I don't know how I can conver FDF reader file into pdf reader

```
using (FdfReader fdfReader = new FdfReader(FdfFileLocation))
                {
                    FdfReader fdfReaderas = new FdfReader(FdfFileLocation); 
                    int fr = fdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                    //annotsReader = new PdfReader(formLocation);
                    for (int page = 1; page <= fdfReaderas.NumberOfPages; ++page)
                    {
                        PdfDictionary pagedic = fdfReaderas.GetPageN(page);
                        PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));

                        if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
                            continue;
                        int couter = 1;
                        foreach (PdfObject A in annotarray.ArrayList)
                        {
                            couter++;

                            PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);
                            PdfString AnnotationTitle = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
                            PdfString AnnotationContent = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
                        }
                    }
```

is there anyway we can find the annotation from fdf file

Comment: Did you find a solution this this question? If so, can you post your solution? I am having the same problem